# What to define model for forms.ChoiceField in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

I have made a form that contains a field like:

```
sex = forms.ChoiceField(choices= SEX)
```

Where:

```
SEX = (
    ('F','Female'),
    ('M','Male'),
    ('U','Unsure'),
    )
```

Now I'm wondering how best the sex field should be defined the model? I know that it can be done like:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('User')
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

But isn't there a better option than CharField?

Comment: The model field should represent the type of the value of the choice; in your case your choices are characters `'F', 'M', 'U'`, so your model should have `sex = models.CharField(max_length=1)` - is this what you are asking?

Comment: Well, I thought there might be better options than CharField in this scenario. (Better, in terms of DB querying.)

Comment: What's the problem with the character field?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've set your choices up as strings so it should be a `CharField(max_length=1, choices=SEX)` in the model. You could then use a [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/) instead of repeating all the logic in a separate form. For example:

```
# models.py
class MyModel(models.Model):
    SEX_CHOICES = (
        ('F', 'Female',),
        ('M', 'Male',),
        ('U', 'Unsure',),
    )
    sex = models.CharField(
        max_length=1,
        choices=SEX_CHOICES,
    )

# forms.py
class MyForm(forms.MyForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['sex',]
```

Comment: So in effect, should I put SEX touple inside models.py page and import 'from django.forms import ModelForm' there to make SEX options also available to forms and avoid redundancy?

Answer (score 2):

**Since Django 4.04**

Now there is a more proper way to do it. [Check it out](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#enumeration-types).
Basically, you'll need to create a enum class like

```py
class SexOptions(models.TextChoices):
    FEMALE = 'F', 'Female'
    MALE = 'M', 'Male'
    UNSURE = 'U', 'Unsure'


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('User')
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=SexOptions.choices)
```

**Old Answer**

```py
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    SEX_FEMALE = 'F'
    SEX_MALE = 'M'
    SEX_UNSURE = 'U'

    SEX_OPTIONS = (
        (SEX_FEMALE, 'Female'),
        (SEX_MALE, 'Male'),
        (SEX_UNSURE, 'Unsure')
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey('User')
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=SEX_OPTIONS)
```

I do prefer this way, it's easier to reference the options inside your code.

```
UserProfile.objects.filter(sex__exact=UserProfile.SEX_UNSURE)
```

Comment: You repeated female twice. And I made a mistake in my edit suggestion :( Unbelievable.

Comment: Thanks, i've removed the duplicated text.

Comment: Since python3.8 it could be more convenient to declare variables just inside declaring `SEX_OPTIONS`, like `SEX_OPTIONS = ((SEX_FEMALE := "F", "Female"), ...)`.